# Simple Email CSS displaying different than in Browser

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am trying to create a simple email with embedded CSS but the result emailed to me comes out very different than what I am seeing in browser.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         body {
         background-color: #96D60D;
         }

         div {
         background-color: white;
         border: 1px solid black;
         margin-top: 100px;
         margin-bottom: 100px;
         margin-right: 150px;
         margin-left: 80px;
         padding: 20px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <center><img src="logo.png"> 
         </center>
         <u>
            <p>
            <H1>API updates list:</H1>
            </p>
         </u>
         <p>
            <b>
         <h2>Successful Entries</h2><br></b>
         <ul>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
         </ul>

         <ul>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
            <li>asdasdasd</li>
         </ul>
         </p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

It looks fantastic in the browser as you can see here:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1EU5RK1DPMG

However, when put into an email, it looks pretty bad:

https://ibb.co/6FVJpZJ

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using Outlook. Some css properties are not fully supported by it and some others are not supported at all. Mailchimp has a cool page with lots of information that I find useful for you. Just check which properties you can use. From my experience, box shadows, margins and border radius have really made me go crazy because the changes don't work.

Here you can even find differences between the desktop and the app version of Outlook: https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/